# Using Java , Hibernate and mySql

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, netbeans

I 'm developing a small java application to learn ORM. And the application run only in default package. When I move it into a other package it shows following error. I want to know how can I move my files (hibernate.cfg.xml , Employee.hbm.xml , Employee.java , ManageEmployee.java)

```
**log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Failed to create sessionFactory object.org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at employ_hibe.ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:27)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:1402)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1424)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1411)
    at employ_hibe.ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:24)
Java Result: 1**
```

Comment: Have you tried creating and adding a `hibernate.cfg.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your hibernate.cfg.xml should be in src/main/resources. In src, it won't be added to your classpath for runtime.

If you are running your project within Eclipse, don't forget in the project preferences in the build path configuration to check that the src/main/resources is not excluded from your class path and is indeed a source folder.